# "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: c#, database, forms

I have a problem when i want to insert values from textboxes to my access database !
When i want to save i get that error ("Data type mismatch in criteria expression")
The code:

```
    string conString = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;"
        + "Data Source=C:\\Users\\Simon\\Desktop\\test5\\test5\\test5\\save.mdb";

    OleDbConnection empConnection = new OleDbConnection(conString);


    string insertStatement = "INSERT INTO aktivnosti_save "
                         + "([ID_uporabnika],[ID_aktivnosti],[kalorij]) "
                         + "VALUES (@ID_uporabnika,@ID_aktivnosti,@kalorij)";

    OleDbCommand insertCommand = new OleDbCommand(insertStatement, empConnection);

    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_uporabnika", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox3.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_zivila", OleDbType.Char).Value = iDTextBox.Text;
    insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@kalorij", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox2.Text;
    empConnection.Open();

    try
    {
        int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
    finally
    {
        empConnection.Close();
        textBox1.Clear();
        textBox2.Clear();   
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2731216/problems-by-inserting-values-from-textboxes

Comment: Are they all definitely character data not numeric? Including the ID fields ID_zivila and @ID_uporabnika?

Comment: @Thomas - Slightly different query but seems to be fundamentally the same issue!

Comment: yeah, couse i didn't get the answer. I just can't get it to work.

Comment: If ypu don't get a satisfactory answer to your question, you should edit it to explain why non eof the responses solve your problem, and/or provide more detail, context.  Please don't create duplicate questions.  It just creates unwarranted clutter.

Comment: Ok i'm sorry for the mess . It won't happen again.:D

Answer (score -1):

you can use String Concatenation in ( string insertStatement = ) instead of

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_uporabnika", OleDbType.Char).Value = textBox3.Text;
```

you can write as example:

```
string insertStatment = "INSERT INTO aktivnosti_save "
                     + "([ID_uporabnika],[ID_aktivnosti],[kalorij]) "
                     + "VALUES ('"+textbox1.text+"','"+textbox2.text+"','"+textbox3.text+"')";
```

try this and let me know about any further problem. u are we